# filter multiple values from product data while holding older values in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am new to React and have been trying to build a filter option.
i managed to filter single values for example category but if i select brand i lose the category value.. i am not sure how to filter multiple values keeping values: category + brand + color any help would be appreciated

heres my code: as you can see i am repeating code

```
import Products from './Products'
import data from '../data'
import { useState } from 'react'

const Main = () => {
    const [productData, setProductData] = useState(data)
    const productCat = [...new Set(data.map((product) => product.category))]
    const productBrand = [...new Set(data.map((product) => product.brand))]

    const filterCategory = (current) => {
        const newItem = data.filter((product) => {
        return product.category === current
        })
        setProductData(newItem)
    }

    const filterBrand = (current) => {
        const newItem = data.filter((product) => {
        return product.brand === current
        })
        setProductData(newItem)
    }

    const renderCategory = productCat.map((product, id) => {
        return (
        <button key={id} onClick={() => filterItem(product)}>
            {product}
        </button>
        )
    })

    const renderBrand = productBrand.map((product, id) => {
        return (
        <button key={id} onClick={() => filterBrand(product)}>
            {product}
        </button>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
        {renderCategory}
        {renderBrand}
        {productData.map((product) => (
            <Products
            img={product.image}
            key={product.id}
            name={product.name}
            category={product.category}
            brand={product.brand}
            price={product.price}
            color={product.color}
            />
        ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is my data structure:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        category: 'Frames',
        brand: 'Alive',
        name: 'Badlands',
        price: 300,
        color: 'grey',
        image:
        'https://www.zenwebcart.com/user_data/images/products/alive/Badlands/alive-badlands_gry02.jpg'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by more than one criteria.

```
const filterItem = (current) => {
    const newItem = data.filter((product) => {
      return product.category === current || product.brand === current; 
            
    });
    setProductData(newItem);
    return newItem

  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but it still doesn't seem to work..
i replaced filterBrand & filterCategory with filterItem

Comment: Forgot to add return statement

Comment: still same.. do ineed to useEffect? seems like i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: As you want to add multiple filters you need to store all those filters somewhere and the filter out the data.
Here, on the `li` element click the filter is saved in a state variable and an useEffect is in place to watch for any filters change and update the filtered product list accordingly

```
import Products from './Products'
import data from '../data'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Main = () => {
    const [productData, setProductData] = useState(data)
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({})

    const productCat = [...new Set(data.map((product) => product.category))]
    const productBrand = [...new Set(data.map((product) => product.brand))]

    useEffect(() => {
        const newData = data.filter((product) => {
        let filterable = false
        for (const filter in filters) filterable = filterable || filters[filter]
        if (!filterable) return true

        for (const filter in filters) {
            if (
            filters[filter] &&
            (product.category === filter || product.brand === filter)
            )
            return true
        }

        return false
        })
        setProductData(newData)
    }, [filters])

    const renderCategory = productCat.map((filter, id) => {
        return (
        <li
            key={id}
            onClick={() =>
            setFilters((state) => ({ ...state, [filter]: !state[filter] }))
            }
        >
            {filter}
        </li>
        )
    })

    const renderBrand = productBrand.map((filter, id) => {
        return (
        <li
            key={id}
            onClick={() =>
            setFilters((state) => ({ ...state, [filter]: !state[filter] }))
            }
        >
            {filter}
        </li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
        {renderCategory}
        {renderBrand}
        {productData.map((product) => (
            <Products
            img={product.image}
            key={product.id}
            name={product.name}
            category={product.category}
            brand={product.brand}
            price={product.price}
            color={product.color}
            />
        ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Comment: Hi, yes i have tried that but it still has the same result
as it only shows the brand or category

Comment: Can you create a Sandbox for you code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-montalcini-hr3f68?file=/src/data.js

Comment: @bukke Update the code. Should work now.

Comment: hey, i updated the code but it still isn't working the way it should.
it seems to only work for 1 click and then after that nothing changes
im sorry im new to this and have been stuck and trying to figure this one out for a while now

Comment: Check this [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-bhabha-g2sf2g?file=/src/components/Main.js)
Seems working to me. I have removed the image just to show that the filters are working.

Comment: maybe i explained my problem or what i want to do wrong.
i checked your updated code but when i for example click "brand:stranger" it works and if i then select "category:handlebars" it still shows "frames" from the current brand & shows "handlebars" from different brand. how it should be is to only show the currently selected category + brand +...hope that makes sense:) thank you!

Comment: So you want to do an `and` instead of `or`. Wait I will update.

Comment: Check this [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-bhabha-g2sf2g?file=/src/components/Main.js)